# Why Maven default-bindings.xml is not updated?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The versions of Maven plugins specified in default-bindings.xml is not latest.
For example, maven-resources-plugin is 2.6, but latest is 3.1.0,
maven-jar-plugin is 2.4, but latest is 3.1.0.
https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml

I think it's not necessary to update default-bindings.xml at every minor version update of plugins.
However, the above is major update.

I know I can change the versions myself if I want.
My Question is why default versions that affect most of the maven users are clearly old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you should always pin all your plugin (and I mean all plugins) inside your build which means define the version of all plugins via `<pluginManagement>..</pluginManagmenet>`   this is best practice and you should never rely on those in Maven Core.

Furthermore there is work done in the background to decouple the artifact handlers (plugin binding) from Maven Core and move it to the plugins[1](https://github.com/apache/maven-ear-plugin/blob/master/src/main/filtered-resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml), [2](https://github.com/apache/maven-war-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources-filtered/META-INF/plexus/components.xml) and [3](https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/filtered-resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml) and so on (which is done in very small steps and will take a long time).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your contribution for maven.

Comment: You mean we should manage all plugins added automatically without noticing?  Maven is such a very useful tool that many not skilled programmers also use.  I was wondering if you could support background settings, though we, programmer, should study and understand the tools we use.

Comment: Usually you should maintain a corporate pom file which contains the definition of all plugins including some configuration options you need. What do you mean by `without noticing`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not worked at the corporations managing pom file consistently, but I will follow your advice in my own development environment.  "without noticing" means I didn't know that plugins were used in the background of maven when I used maven for the first time and then for a while.